# Understanding how to read and write different formats to a binary file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, binary

I'm trying to understand how to read and write multiple types in matlab but I'm not really having any luck understanding where I'm going wrong.

For example, let's say I want to write a string and a double to a binary file.

```
my_string='hello world';
my_double=4.45;

fid=fopen('test.bin','wb');
fwrite(fid,my_string,'char');
fwrite(fid,my_double,'double');
fclose(fid);
```

And now I want to read back that string and double. The first method I saw was someone suggested just loading the entire file into a byte array and reading chunks at a time. However, doing that gives me nothing.

```
fid=fopen('test.bin','rb');
my_data=fread(fid);
    my_data=[]
```

`my_data` is just a blank array.

Another thing I tried was reading in the data with the size.

```
my_data=fread(fid2,size(my_string),'char')
    my_data=[]
```

This gives me a blank array as well. Even reading it in as an integer won't work.

So how can I write mixed types to read back later?

Comment: might be just a typo but in your last `fread` statement you are reading from `fid2` instead of `fid` ... you might want to check that.

Comment: by the way, the lines `my_data=[]` in your examples, are there actual part of your code or is that just your way of showing the output ? If it is part of your code that's your problem, you are assigning an empty array to `my_data`, overwriting whatever the variable contained after having read the file data.

Answer (score 1):

First, writing as you did:

```
my_string='hello world';
my_double=4.45;

fid=fopen('doubletest.bin','wb');
fwrite(fid,my_string,'char');
fwrite(fid,my_double,'double');
fclose(fid);
```

And then for reading both char and double

```
fid2=fopen('doubletest.bin','rb');
my_data=fread(fid2,size(my_string),'*char');
my_data
my_data=fread(fid2,size(my_double),'*double');
my_data
% my_data=fread(fid2);
% my_data
```

Output is

```
my_data =

hello world


my_data =

    4.4500
```

Comment: But this is for formatted files? I have to use binary files because of space issues unfortunately.

Comment: This really doesn't answer anything. The question is specifically asking for reading and writing to binary files, not plain text files. In any case you are only just referring to the writing part as well.

Comment: @Bernhard I was away, edited the answer to have binary read/write as well, can you please remove your downvote now?

Comment: Fair enough, but you didn't get back the double value.

Comment: @Bernhard added answer for double as well

Comment: @be_good_do_good Nice, I edited a bit to clean up, feel free to revert if you do not agree.